# $\lim \frac{a^n - b^n}{a^n +b^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $c_n = \lim \frac{a^n - b^n}{a^n +b^n}$ , $a,b \in (0, \infty)$. to find limit of sequence.

Case 1 : a = b , $c_n$ is constant sequence 0

Case 2: $a > b $, $ c_n = \frac{1- (\frac{b}{a})^n}{1+ (\frac{b}{a})^n} $.

$\frac{b}{a} < 1$, so $(\frac{b}{a})^n \to 0$. hence limit of $c_n = 1$

Case 3: $a < b$.

I don't know how to go about Case 3. Thanks

Comment: When you wrote $a_n$, did you mean $a^n$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantosyes corrected

Comment: $ c_{n}=\frac{-\left(b^{n}-a^{n}\right)}{b^{n}+a^{n}} $ so it really isn't much different than case 2.

Comment: Not at the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a<b$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^n-b^n}{a^n+b^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac ab\right)^n-1}{\left(\frac ab\right)^n+1}=-1,
$$
since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac ab\right)^n=0$.